# A question regarding quantum entanglement

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, quantum-spin, quantum-entanglement, epr-experiment

According to wiki,

> Quantum entanglement is the physical phenomenon that occurs when a group of particles are generated, interact, or share spatial proximity in a way such that the quantum state of each particle of the group cannot be described independently of the state of the others, including **when the particles are separated by a large distance**.

Now from other sources, as a newbie, I understand that the particle that is being separated should be free of other interaction. If one particle is being separated from other by a large distance than there must be some action required to separate it (so it is logically not possible to separate the particle without interacting with it). So, am I missing anything?

How can both conditions be true at the same time?

1. Separate a particle
2. No interaction with the particle?

Comment: Particles have non-zero velocity. So they can theoretically speaking move a long distance away from the other particle.

Comment: A major "detail": It isn't the particles that are entangled, but rather the quantum *modes*. A single photon by itself can exhibit entanglement with the vacuum. I'm just saying this because it's misleading to think of particles themselves as the carriers of entanglement.

Comment: @Karthik in most examples, educators say that "lets take the particle to another Galaxy". I think thats where the misunderstanding comes from. So you mean with their natural velocity they can autonomously travel at distance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're misreading the sentence. The sentence is just trying to say that the distance (=separation) between particles as such does not matter at all for their entanglement, not that someone is actively separating them. A less ambiguous phrasing would perhaps be "including when the particles are a large distance apart".

There is no additional process of separating the particles through interaction implied here - the spatial separation often comes about naturally from the process that creates them, e.g. when the entangled pair is emitted from some process with the constraint that their total momentum be zero, then they'll move in opposite directions with equal speeds, hence separating themselves from each other as time passes, without any need for additional interaction.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Now, when two particles naturally become separated that means there must be unequal amount of force applied naturally on different particles (because otherwise, they both would have been staying for eternity at (along the path) where they were). So, what would be the differences between the interaction imposed unequal force and the natural unequal force on the particles in physical context?

Comment: @SazzadHissainKhan I don't know what you mean - the particles are *created* with different velocities by whatever process creates them (e.g. [down conversion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spontaneous_parametric_down-conversion)), there's no "forces" here. This isn't classical mechanics, and the particles didn't exist prior to being created with different velocities.

Comment: @SazzadHissainKhan As an analogy, if I say two people have met one another, you do not conclude the two people are still in the same place. They may now be far apart, and the specifics of how they came to be far apart are not important to the statement that they have met one another. With the particles they are already entangled even when they are close together, the fascinating detail is that they remain entangled when they separate. If one particle whacks into another, they bounce off each other and go their separate ways, they may still be entangled when they get far apart.